# IndentationError expected an indented block for Network automication

Tags: python

The code is set run a command in my cisco device -- cache the output and query the outcome but if there is another line within the same outcome then to execute it.

```js
peeringip = raw_input("Enter the customer's peering IP : ")
    print
    print
    sitee = raw_input('Enter the Site(/col/ash/')
    site = sitee.upper()
    def cisco(routername,shrninc,showipint,showtunnel,shipprefix):
     conn = SSH2()
     conn.connect(routername)
     conn.login(account1)
     conn.execute('Terminal Length 0')
     bgpstatements = shrninc + peeringip
     print "Router Name: ",routername
     conn.execute(bgpstatements)
     showcomoutputbgp = conn.response
     if 'neighbor' in showcomoutputbgp:
       print "============"
       print "-------------------"
       print "============"
       print "-------------------"
       print
       print "BGP configuration : ",conn.response
       print
       print "CHECKING PREFIX-LIST"
    elif 'ROUTE' in showcomoutputbgp:
     chkprefix = re.search("ROUTE",showcomoutputbgp)
     prefix_name = chkprefix.group()
     locate_prefix = shipprefix + prefix_name
     conn.execute(locate_prefix)
     print "PREFIX-LIST INFO : "
     else:
     print "No BGP neighbor"
```

No output for the Elif...

Comment: Do you have any idea of what you are doing?

Comment: Python is indentation specific and your indentation is wrong.

Comment: What's up with the empty `print` statements ?

Comment: @alfasin I was thinking the same thing. I think he hasn't  learned `\n`.

Comment: i used the empty print for the output be readable or a lot better. there is really no reason for the code to not execute if there is an empty print... 
and yes in the process of learning and so far i've done a really good job.. im just wondering per my last comment...Thanks for constructive criticism

Comment: Are the empty prints supposed to be for blank lines?

Comment: Yes, blank lines. The code is flowing but is not executing the elif as if when calling the showcomoutputbgp is empty.

Lines are good guys trust me.. is just whenever i add the code "not sure which one to use" so i use HTML and throws the lining off.

Comment: @DGo instead of doing `print "-------------------"` and then another `print` to add a blank line, you can do as DeliriousSyntax suggested: `print "-------------------\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent this section because of the `if` statement. Also, instead of all the blank prints you can add \n to your previous prints. It makes it look neater and easier to read.

```
def cisco(routername,shrninc,showipint,showtunnel,shipprefix):
    conn = SSH2()
    conn.connect(routername)
    conn.login(account1)
    conn.execute('Terminal Length 0')
    bgpstatements = shrninc + peeringip
    print "Router Name: ",routername
    conn.execute(bgpstatements)
    showcomoutputbgp = conn.response
    if 'neighbor' in showcomoutputbgp:
        print "============"
        print "-------------------"
        print "============"
        print "-------------------\n"
        print "BGP configuration : ",conn.response + "\n"
        print "CHECKING PREFIX-LIST"
    elif 'prefix-list' in showcomoutputbgp:
        chkprefix = re.search(r'(prefix-list)',showcomoutputbgp)
        prefix_name = chkprefix.group()
        locate_prefix = shipprefix + prefix_name
        conn.execute(locate_prefix)
        print "PREFIX-LIST INFO : ",conn.response + "\n" 
    else:
        print "No BGP neighbor""
```

Comment: Okay, I have moved the code as per below but still the ELIF is like it's not being executed or as if the showcomoutbgp has a limitation per indentations or if it get's cut off after being executed:

Comment: if 'neighbor' in showcomoutputbgp:
  print "============"
  print "-------------------"
  print "============"
  print "-------------------"
  print
  print "BGP configuration : ",conn.response
  print
  print "CHECKING PREFIX-LIST"
 elif 'prefix-list' in showcomoutputbgp:
  chkprefix = re.search(r'(prefix-list)',showcomoutputbgp)
  prefix_name = chkprefix.group()
  locate_prefix = shipprefix + prefix_name
  conn.execute(locate_prefix)
  print "PREFIX-LIST INFO : ",conn.response
  print 
 else:
  print "No BGP neighbor"
 print
 print
 print "============"

Comment: After being executed there is no output:

  print "PREFIX-LIST INFO : ",conn.response
  print 
 else:
  print "No BGP neighbor"
 print

Comment: Is the second `if` in your post supposed to be an `elif` not an `if` ??

Comment: I was in the process of updating guys... Kinda new to this. Taking on a project at work just trying to save an extra command on the router by doing the eliif  rathen than doing a separate if

Comment: You need your `elif` to align with the `if` and `else` you don't need to indent that.

Comment: I'll just fix all the indent's in my answer give me 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

```html
def cisco(routername,shrninc,showipint,showtunnel,shipprefix):
 conn = SSH2()
 conn.connect(routername)
 conn.login(account1)
 conn.execute('Terminal Length 0')
 bgpstatements = shrninc + peeringip
 print "Router Name: ",routername
 conn.execute(bgpstatements)
 showcomoutputbgp = conn.response
 if 'neighbor' in showcomoutputbgp:
  print "============"
  print "-------------------"
  print "============"
  print "-------------------"
  print
  print "BGP configuration : ",conn.response
  print
  print "CHECKING PREFIX-LIST"
 elif 'prefix-list' in showcomoutputbgp:
  chkprefix = re.search(r'(prefix-list)',showcomoutputbgp)
  prefix_name = chkprefix.group()
  locate_prefix = shipprefix + prefix_name
  conn.execute(locate_prefix)
  print "PREFIX-LIST INFO : ",conn.response
  print 
 else:
  print "No BGP neighbor"
```